# Choose class by current date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a icon, and i need to change its color if modified date is = current date.

logic:
if `inventory.modified = time` then apply style.

in controller :

`$scope.time = new Date();`

Template: 
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" ng-class=""></span>`

api modified:
`modified: "2014-04-07T13:04:25.676000",`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change logic a little bit.

Looking at timestamp format, style would be applied for only 1/100000th of a second. I think chance to get javascript running at that EXACT time is pretty low.

You probably want one of following:

1. Apply style if it is same minute
2. Apply style if time matches and remove it after specified interval (say, 15 seconds)

Either way, `date` filter should be usefull: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

**EDIT:**

in JS:

```
// do this once, so we don't need convert again    
$scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'shortDate');

...
inventory.$modified = $filter('date')(new Date(inventory.modified), 'shortDate');
```

in template:

```
<span ng-class="active: inventory.$modified == time"> {{ inventory }} </span>
```

Although, for performance I would precalculate field `inventory.$modifiedToday` (=true/false) so each iteration would not need to recalculate. Template would be like this:

```
<span ng-class="active: inventory.$modifiedToday"> {{ inventory }} </span>
```

Comment: i need to apply it if its current date, i dont need minutes and seconds

Comment: Date as in YYYY-mm-dd?

Comment: i have `$scope.inventories = new Inventory().query().$object;` I dont think that i can write at my controller inventory.$modified ?

Comment: How you are retrieving your data (which library)?

Comment: I am using `Restangular` , here i get all objects `$scope.inventories = new Inventory().query().$object;`

Comment: You can either iterate over `$scope.inventories` and add new field, or use Restangular's `addResponseInterceptor` to add field there. Which way is better to use depends on situation.